# Infinite ajax scroll did not working in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

I am trying to use infinite ajax scroll plugin in my project. I just followed the official website and include the necessary javascript files. Following is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
       <div class="bootstrap-card">
       <img src="{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="card imag">
       <div class="overlay">
       <a class="info" href="#">View Details</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="bootstrap-card">
        <img src="{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="card imag">
        <div class="overlay">
        <a class="info" href="#">View Details</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
       <div class="bootstrap-card">
       <img src="{% static 'images/1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="card imag">
       <div class="overlay">
       <a class="info" href="#">View Details</a>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{% static 'hw1/js/callback.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'hw1/js/jquery-ias.min.js' %}"></script>

<div id="pagination">
    <a href="page2.html" class="next">next</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container: '.row',
        item: '.col-lg-4',
        pagination: '#pagination',
        next: '.next',
        delay: 1250
      });
    });

    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
    ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 2}));
    ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({text: "You reached the end"}));
</script>
```

So here page2.html is another page in and it does exist.

So does anybody know why the error message is:

> (index):244 Uncaught ReferenceError: ias is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):244
>   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery.ias is not a function TypeError: jQuery.ias is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:8000/:235:24)
>       at j (http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
>       at k (http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue. You define `var ias` inside the jQuery `ready` callback but are trying to reference the ias variable outside of that callback. Outside of that callback, the `ias` variable doesn't exist. Additionally, because the callback is asynchronous, the callback won't be called until the DOM is fully loaded. This means your calls to `ias.extension()` are happening before the page has even had a chance to load, which is why the `ready` callback exists in the first place.

To fix this, put your calls to `ias.extension()` inside the callback as well so they they're all in the same scope where both jquery and ias have been initialized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container: '.row',
    item: '.col-lg-4',
    pagination: '#pagination',
    next: '.next',
    delay: 1250
  });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
  ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 2}));
  ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({text: "You reached the end"}));
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your explanation. However, I still get the same error. It seems it always looking for the function defined in jquery-3.1.1.min.js. The error message is:jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery.ias is not a function TypeError: jQuery.ias is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/:235:24)
    at j (http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262)

Comment: @user2970089 does http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-ias.min.js return javascript or does it give an error? If it gives an error, your static files are probably not set up correctly or you have a typo in your urls.

Comment: It return me the javascript. I checked there is no typo and I also use the similar things to add other javascript files. So I am confused why this function is not able to be found...

Comment: Another error message it shows is:  jquery-ias.min.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at http://localhost:8000/static/hw1/js/jquery-ias.min.js:13:6783(anonymous function) @ jquery-ias.min.js:13

Comment: It seems like the plugin has a bug, then. Go report it to them on their github page.